# Unix change desktop background seamlessly

Tags: python, bash, unix, cron, python-imaging-library

So i have a python script which generates an image, and saves over the old image which used to be the background image.

I tried to make it run using `crontab`, but couldn't get that to work, so now i just have a bash script which runs once in my `.bashrc` whdn i first log in (i have a `if [ firstRun ]` kind of thing in there).

The problem is, that every now and then, when the background updates, it flashes black before it does - which is not very nice!

I currently have it running once a second, but i don't think it's the python that is causing the black screens, and more the way the image is changed over...

Is there a way I can prevent these ugly black screens between updates?

Here's all the code to run it, if you want to try it out...

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
    import colorsys
    from random import gauss

```
xSize, ySize = 1600,900

im = Image.new('RGBA', (xSize, ySize), (0, 0, 0, 0)) 
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im) 

class Cube(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tl = (0,0)
        self.tm = (0,0)
        self.tr = (0,0)
        self.tb = (0,0)
        self.bl = (0,0)
        self.bm = (0,0)
        self.br = (0,0)

    def intify(self):
        for prop in [self.tl, self.tm, self.tr, self.tb, self.bl, self.bm, self.br]:
            prop = [int(i) for i in prop]

def drawCube((x,y), size, colour=(255,0,0)):

    p = Cube()

    colours = [list(colorsys.rgb_to_hls(*[c/255.0 for c in colour])) for _ in range(3)]
    colours[0][1] -= 0
    colours[1][1] -= 0.2
    colours[2][1] -= 0.4
    colours = [tuple([int(i*255) for i in colorsys.hls_to_rgb(*colour)]) for colour in colours]


    p.tl = x,y #Top Left
    p.tm = x+size/2, y-size/4 #Top Middle
    p.tr = x+size, y #Top Right
    p.tb = x+size/2, y+size/4 #Top Bottom
    p.bl = x, y+size/2 #Bottom Left
    p.bm = x+size/2, y+size*3/4 #Bottom Middle
    p.br = x+size, y+size/2 #Bottom Right

    p.intify()

    draw.polygon((p.tl, p.tm, p.tr, p.tb), fill=colours[0])
    draw.polygon((p.tl, p.bl, p.bm, p.tb), fill=colours[1])
    draw.polygon((p.tb, p.tr, p.br, p.bm), fill=colours[2])

    lineColour = (0,0,0)
    lineThickness = 2

    draw.line((p.tl, p.tm), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.tl, p.tb), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.tm, p.tr), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.tb, p.tr), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.tl, p.bl), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.tb, p.bm), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.tr, p.br), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.bl, p.bm), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)
    draw.line((p.bm, p.br), fill=lineColour, width=lineThickness)


# -------- Actually do the drawing

size = 100

#Read in file of all colours, and random walk them
with open("/home/will/Documents/python/cubeWall/oldColours.dat") as coloursFile:
    for line in coloursFile:
        oldColours = [int(i) for i in line.split()]

oldColours = [int(round(c + gauss(0,1.5)))%255 for c in oldColours]


colours = [[ int(c*255) for c in colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(i/255.0, 1, 1)] for i in oldColours]


with open("/home/will/Documents/python/cubeWall/oldColours.dat", "w") as coloursFile:
    coloursFile.write(" ".join([str(i) for i in oldColours]) + "\n")


for i in range(xSize/size+2):
    for j in range(2*ySize/size+2):
        if j%3 == 0:
            drawCube((i*size,j*size/2), size, colour=colours[(i+j)%3])
        elif j%3 == 1:
            drawCube(((i-0.5)*size,(0.5*j+0.25)*size), size, colour=colours[(i+j)%3])


im2 = im.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
im2.save("cubes.png")
#im2.show()
```

and then just run this:

#!/bin/sh

```
while [ 1 ]
do
    python drawCubes.py
sleep 1
done
```

And set the desktop image to be `cubes.png`

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can change the current wallaper (in Gnome 3 compatible desktops) by running

```
import os
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file://%(path)s" % {'path':absolute_path})
os.system("gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-options wallpaper")
```

Comment: Do you think this will be better than just changing the file that is currently being used for the background, and letting it update itself?

Comment: Actually, just overwriting the file might be the worst possible method. By using gsettings, (not tested) you have far more chances to see a smooth fade between pictures.

Comment: Yah i realised this might be the case afterwards, surely the gsettings will send out some kind of signal. I'll give it a try. Cheers.

Comment: okay, so i tried this (just using `gsettings` from the command line), and it didn't work. If i run `gnome-session --version` i get `3.2.1`... Any ideas?

Comment: You might need to wrap your file URI between double quotes if it contains a space. Eg. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/steve/Images/wallpaper/Almora_mbr/Almora_2560x1600_Grain.jpg"
`

Comment: don't think that's it, there's no space in it, and when i do `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.background picture uri` it is correct, the background image is just not what i set it to. I'm using ubuntu MINT, so could there be another desktop manager installed over the top of gnome?

Comment: This is possible but unlikely. If your desktop is Gnome 3 or Cinnamon or compatible, and your file browser is Nautilus/Files or Nemo, it should work.

Comment: Pretty sure i'm using the MATE interface rather than Cinnamon.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MATE, you're using a fork of Gnome 2.x. The method I found for Gnome 2 is : `gconftool-2 --set --type string --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename <absolute image path>`.

The method we tried before would have worked in Gnome Shell.